# how to avoid deadlock while updating 2 rows in mysql

Tags: mysql, deadlock

This is a interview problem.

There is a perl program that updates the database, and it could run in different processes.
One process may execute a transaction like: update row A -> update row B -> commit.
The other process may execute a transaction like: update row B -> update row A -> commit.
The rows need to be updated is selected before or in the transaction.

I was asked how to avoid deadlocks without changing the transaction logic (I cannot commit after updating A and commit again after updating B).

They want me to propose at least **3 different methods**.
What I know is to use "select .. for update" when selecting row A and B. Can anyone help to suggest some other methods?

Comment: This is a better fit for [dba.se]

Comment: I would suggest changing the transaction logic.